# Is this exponential family pdf of full rank?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are iid random variables from a distribution with Lebesgue pdf $$f_\theta(x) = \exp\left\{-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 - \xi(\theta)\right\}$$

It is easy to show that the statistic $T= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)$ is minimal sufficient (using theorems that don't have to do with the family being of full rank), but I am having trouble deducing whether this exponential family is of full rank. The corresponding parameter $\eta(\theta) = \left( -\frac{1}{\sigma^4}, \frac{4\mu}{\sigma^4}, -\frac{6\mu^2}{\sigma^4}, \frac{4\mu^3}{\sigma^4} \right)$ is four components. Does this have anything to do with it?

I know that the parameter space contains open sets, as $\sigma > 0$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ can vary freely with respect to each other (there is no relationship between them), so it seems that it is full rank. I think I'm getting confused by the dimensionality of the parameter. Do I have to put it into canonical form first to see if it's full rank?